# Images/file upload to mysql database not working

Tags: php

I'm currently having a bit of a rough time uploading an image to my database. I currently have multiple variables/inputs being uploaded from one form - one if these inputs is an image file upload. The file seems to make it do the database, but when I try to retrieve the image via a PHP script, it simply returns "Array", rather than the image. Any help? Thanks!

Here's the upload code:

```
               // if the form's submit button is clicked, we need to process the form
            if (isset($_POST['submit']))
            {
                    // get the form data
                            $projectname = htmlentities($_POST['projectname'], ENT_QUOTES);
                            $item = htmlentities($_POST['item'], ENT_QUOTES);
                            $description = htmlentities($_POST['description'], ENT_QUOTES);
                            $neededby = htmlentities($_POST['neededby'], ENT_QUOTES);
                            $shipping= htmlentities($_POST['shipping'], ENT_QUOTES);
                            $revisions = htmlentities($_POST['revisions'], ENT_QUOTES);
                            $price = htmlentities($_POST['price'], ENT_QUOTES);
                            $paid = htmlentities($_POST['paid'], ENT_QUOTES);
                            $ordered1 = htmlentities($_POST['ordered1'], ENT_QUOTES);
                            $ordered2 = htmlentities($_POST['ordered2'], ENT_QUOTES);
                            $ordered3 = htmlentities($_POST['ordered3'], ENT_QUOTES);
                            $received1 = htmlentities($_POST['received1'], ENT_QUOTES);
                            $received2 = htmlentities($_POST['received2'], ENT_QUOTES);
                            $received3 = htmlentities($_POST['received3'], ENT_QUOTES);
                            $shipped1 = htmlentities($_POST['shipped1'], ENT_QUOTES);
                            $shipped2 = htmlentities($_POST['shipped2'], ENT_QUOTES);
                            $shipped3 = htmlentities($_POST['shipped3'], ENT_QUOTES);
                            $tracking = htmlentities($_POST['tracking'], ENT_QUOTES);
                            $delivered = htmlentities($_POST['delivered'], ENT_QUOTES);
                            $thestatus = htmlentities($_POST['thestatus'], ENT_QUOTES);
                            $photo=($_FILES['photo']); 




                   if ($projectname == '')
                            {
                                    // if they are empty, show an error message and display the form
                                    $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in project name!';
                                    renderForm($projectname, $item, $description, $neededby, $shipping, $revisions, $price, $paid, $ordered1, $ordered2, $ordered3, $received1, $received2, $received3, $shipped1, $shipped2, $shipped3, $tracking, $delivered, $thestatus, $photo, $error, $id);
                            }

                            else
                            {
                            // insert the new record into the database
                            if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT todo (projectname, item, description, neededby, shipping, revisions, price, paid, ordered1, ordered2, ordered3, received1, received2, received3, shipped1, shipped2, shipped3, tracking, delivered, photo, thestatus) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"))
                            {
                                    $stmt->bind_param("sssssssssssssssssssss", $projectname, $item, $description, $neededby, $shipping, $revisions, $price, $paid, $ordered1, $ordered2, $ordered3, $received1, $received2, $received3, $shipped1, $shipped2, $shipped3, $tracking, $delivered, $photo, $thestatus);
                                    $stmt->execute();
                                    $stmt->close();
                            }

                            // show an error if the query has an error
                            else
                            {
                                    echo "ERROR: Could not prepare SQL statement.";
                            }



                            // redirec the user
                            header("Location: main.php");
                    }

            }
```

And the file retrieve code:

```
<?php 
mysql_connect("localhost","MYUSER","MYPASS"); 
mysql_select_db("MYDB"); 
$query = "SELECT photo FROM todo where id=$id"; 
$result = MYSQL_QUERY($query); 
$data = MYSQL_RESULT($result,0,"photo"); 
Header( "Content-type: $type"); 
print $data; 
?>
```

The mysql column is a BLOB type.

Here is an image so you can get some visuals on what I'm saying:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pHwB.png

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want to store the image in the database rather than just saving the file to a directory and saving the path of the file to the database? Saving the file path would be much nice to the database than storing the entire image.

Comment: That's first and foremost because `$_FILES['photo']` *is* an array which contains information about the uploaded file. It's not the uploaded file itself. Have you tried [consulting the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) about file uploads?

Comment: @knittledan I believe that BLOB data types are stored outside the table proper, and the table just includes a pointer to the information. So storing an image in the database shouldn't cause issues for normal queries (though it might slow down backup and replication).

Comment: I haven't even thought of this! Doh! That should be a bit easier - thanks knittledan.

Comment: @deceze thanks for the reference. I'll take a look.

Comment: could be that because every query from a DB comes back as an array and thus must seperate it's information, like in a loop, to extract the information into non-array format?  Seems you are just taking the "result" and trying to display it rather than extract the information from the result set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this tutorial

http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php

put the file name on variable then insert it into the database (I'm expecting you know how to retrieve data from databases)

Answer (score 1):

```
$fileName = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$tmpName  = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['image']['size'];
$fileType = $_FILES['image']['type'];

$fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
$photo = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
$photo = addslashes($photo);
fclose($fp);

if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
    $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
}


//and here your insert query as i remember you can try it


HTML CODE:

   <input type=\"file\" name=\"image\" />


and here is how you retrive it

echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode( $row['imageContent'] ) . '" />';
```

But i don't recommend you doing that because it will make your database not loading fast so save the image to a folder and onlyt the name in the databse

note i have got this code from a forum and don;t remember it's name sorry

Comment: Why are you adding slashes to a binary file, moreover twice?

Comment: well i haven;t written that code myself but i belive it worked fine with me cuz i have used it once but never did again. but i belive it is adding it to the tmp_name and the name itslef and used this code like 2 years ago so i relly don't remember it so much sorry

Comment: Hmm, personally, I wouldn't use code I don't fully understand, much less repost it on a public forum with my name attached to it...

Comment: well sorry i just wanted to help the guy over here who knows he might needed it you know sometimes ppl need the code urgent

Answer (score 1):

It's generally a pretty bad idea to upload an image directly to the database. The reason is because after a while, reading and uploading files from the database will overload the database.

A better solution would be to upload the image to a folder on the server, and then save the filename and location in the database instead.